# Конвертер чисел с округлением до буквенного окончания

Tags: php

Как можно сделать такое

```
ecли 100 => вывести "100"
ecли 1 000 => вывести "1K"
ecли 1 500 => вывести "1.5K"
ecли 1 000 000 => вывести "1M"
ecли 1 500 000 => вывести "1.5M"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$number = '1000000';

$types = array('', 'K', 'M');
$TYPE = 0;
while (abs($number) >= 1000) {
    $number /= 1000;
    $TYPE++;
}

echo $number . $types[$TYPE];
```

Comment: Элегантное решение :)